# Are bonuses included in the salary base requirement for FLSA overtime exemption rules?

Tags: overtime, exempt, flsa

The Fair Labor Standards Act (FLSA) specifies (among other things) a minimum salary requirement for an employee to qualify as exempt from their overtime regulations.

**Can bonuses be included in that salary calculation?**

Comment: This question was created as my original answer on [this question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/69832/) was answering the general case of bonuses instead of the OP's specific question. Note that this is *not* an off-topic legal question as questions that a HR professional (and consequently a manager or small-business owner) should know the answer to have been deemed on-topic here. This can be answered by simply stating the relevant regulations (as I have done), it doesn't require interpretation of the law for a specific situation

Answer (score 3):

**Until December 1<sup>st</sup> 2016, bonuses cannot be considered at all** for the FLSA overtime exemption salary requirement.

Once the upcoming changes to the FLSA overtime rules come into effect on December 1<sup>st</sup> 2016, [**up to 10% of the minimum salary can be made up of *nondiscretionary* bonuses and/or commissions**](http://www.wagehourinsights.com/2016/05/new-rules-announced-47476-minimum-salary-effective-1212016/):

> Bonuses and Commissions May Now Be Included: In a somewhat surprising concession to employers, the new rules will allow non-discretionary bonuses, incentive payments and commissions to count for up to 10% of the minimum salary, provided these amounts are paid at least quarterly.

Details of the upcoming changes are outlined in [my answer here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/69512/25739). Further detail on the salary and duties tests are in [my answer here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/52271/can-my-employer-demand-that-i-show-up-to-work-15-minutes-before-my-shift-but-not/52303#52303).

Full details of the changes are covered in the United States Department of Labor's Wage and Hour Division's [FAQ on the "Overtime Final Rule"](https://www.dol.gov/whd/overtime/final2016/faq.htm#N1). I have reproduced the section on bonuses in full here:

> ## NONDISCRETIONARY BONUSES AND INCENTIVE PAYMENTS
>
> #### May employers use bonuses to satisfy part of the new standard salary level test?
>
> Yes. The Department is changing the regulations to allow
> nondiscretionary bonuses and incentive payments (including
> commissions) to satisfy up to 10 percent of the standard salary test
> requirement. Such bonuses include, for example, nondiscretionary
> incentive bonuses tied to productivity or profitability (e.g. a bonus
> based on the specified percentage of the profits generated by a
> business in the prior quarter). The Department recognizes that some
> businesses pay significantly larger bonuses; where larger bonuses are
> paid, however, the amount attributable toward the EAP standard salary
> level is capped at 10 percent of the required salary amount.
>
> For employers to credit nondiscretionary bonuses and incentive
> payments (including commissions) toward a portion of the standard
> salary level test, such payments must be paid on a quarterly or more
> frequent basis.
>
> #### What's the difference between a discretionary bonus and a nondiscretionary bonus?
>
> Nondiscretionary bonuses and incentive payments (including
> commissions) are forms of compensation promised to employees to induce
> them to work more efficiently or to remain with the company. Examples
> include bonuses for meeting set production goals, retention bonuses,
> and commission payments based on a fixed formula.
>
> By contrast, discretionary bonuses are those for which the decision to
> award the bonus and the payment amount is at the employer's sole
> discretion and not in accordance with any preannounced standards. An
> example would be an unannounced bonus or spontaneous reward for a
> specific act.
>
> #### May employers make a catch-up payment in the event that an employee doesn't receive enough in nondiscretionary bonuses and incentive payments (including commissions) in a given quarter to remain exempt?
>
> Yes, if an employee does not earn enough in nondiscretionary bonuses
> and incentive payments (including commissions) in a given quarter to
> retain their exempt status the Department permits a "catch-up" payment
> at the end of the quarter. The employer has one pay period to make up
> for the shortfall (up to 10 percent of the standard salary level for
> the preceding 13 week period). Any such catch-up payment will count
> only toward the prior quarter's salary amount and not toward the
> salary amount in the quarter in which it was paid. If the employer
> chooses not to make the catch-up payment, the employee would be
> entitled to overtime pay for any overtime hours worked during the
> quarter.
>
> #### Does the Final Rule change how employers may use bonuses to satisfy the salary level for highly compensated employees (HCEs)?
>
> No, the Department has not made changes to how employers may use
> bonuses to meet the salary level component of the HCE test. To claim
> the HCE exemption under the Final Rule, employers must pay workers at
> least the standard weekly salary level of $913 per week on a salary or
> fee basis, while the remainder of the total annual compensation may
> include commissions, nondiscretionary bonuses, and other
> nondiscretionary compensation. Because employers may fulfill almost
> two-thirds of the HCE total annual compensation requirement with
> commissions, nondiscretionary bonuses, and other forms of
> nondiscretionary deferred compensation, the Department determined that
> it would not be appropriate to permit employers to also use
> nondiscretionary bonuses and incentive payments to satisfy the
> standard salary amount.
>
> <sup>Source: [Final Rule: Overtime](https://www.dol.gov/whd/overtime/final2016/faq.htm#N1), United States Department of Labor's Wage and Hour Division's, retrieved 2016-06-15.</sup>